# NameError even when variable is initialize

Tags: python, opencv

I'm coding on Python (first timer) trying to program an artificial vision algorithm  which recognizes when a TV channel is showing a spot or a regular TV show (there are no TV logos when a spot is running on TV).

The code I'm working with is this

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Telecinco.mp4')

count = 0
template = cv2.imread('telecinco_logo.png',0)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,None,fx=1,fy=1,interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    if count == 0:
        count = 1
        cv2.imwrite('image.png', frame)

    w, h = template.shape[::-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.7
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        logo_img = frame[pt[1]:pt[1]+h,pt[0]:pt[0]+w]
        cv2.rectangle(frame, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Captura',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Logo encontrado', logo_img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, python is giving me an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "logoDeteccion.py", line 27, in <module>
 cv2.imshow('Logo encontrado', logo_img)
 NameError: name 'logo_img' is not defined
```

And I'm really confused. logo_img is always declared (or should be). When commenting that line program is running fine, but of course doesn't do what it should do.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: your code says that `logo_img` is defined only if `zip(*loc[::-1])` has something in it, add some `print('foo')` into the for loop to verify whether it enters the loop

Comment: You create the var `logo_img` only if this happens `for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):` but if that's None and the loop does actually nothing, u won't have that var, which then creates your error. That's likely where the issue appears. Edit: Derte was 7 seconds faster than me! haha. Should I delete this comment?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop, you try to show `logo_img` to the screen.

If it does not exists, then you can wait for `zip(*loc[::-1])` to have an actual value.

See the code below:

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
    try:
        cv2.imshow('Logo encontrado', logo_img)
    except NameError:
        pass #Go for next loop and check to see if logo_img exists
```